# Can we have a physics by using other mathematics except calculus?

Tags: time, discrete, calculus, laws-of-physics

We (I) always have been said that we don't need to real values, we just need to differences. For example, $\mathrm du=C_v\mathrm dT$ and $\Delta u=\int_{T_1}^{T_2}C_v\mathrm dT$.

So, I have some questions:

1. How are we sure that we don't need real values (for example initial values at zero time)?
2. Can we determine initial values at zero time (for example $u(0)$)?
3. Is it possible to have a physics by other mathematics except [calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus) so that we don't face with such this problems (initial values problem)?

Comment: Hmmm.  Can you elaborate?  Im not sure i follow

Comment: @user122066 As far as I know all of physical laws have been expressed by calculus, for example $\frac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(m(t)\vec v(t))=\vec F(t)$ so what are the values of $m(0)$, $\vec v(0)$ and $\vec F(0)$? How are we sure that we don't need to them?

Comment: Oh man....i vaguely recall some weird obscure field along the lines of what youre talking about.  Ill tey and remember and look it up in the morning and see if it is what im thinking.  It's an interesting question for sure.  Calculus (and any other maths) is just a tool kit we use in hopes of quantifying the universe.  Why, exactly, physics can be expressed and probed with mathematics is a deep and weird philosophocal problem.  Was it wigner who wrote an essay on this? "The unreasonable effectiveness of mathematics for physics"

Comment: Calculus is how you handle ("locally flat") continuous things that aren't linear, by zooming into them -- as long as these exist, you'll need calculus in physics. But the questioner seems to have an irrational fear of calculus. Calculus isn't hard, it's just that retarded school systems divide physics as "calculus-based" and "non-calculus". Calculus is just a mathematical tool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stephen Wolfram has been [a great advocate for re-building physics on discrete models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_New_Kind_of_Science), and Gerard 't Hooft has done a [cellular automa interpretation of quantum mechanics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.1548).

But frankly those kinds of thing aren't going to push calculus out of the way because we don't use it out of some kind of abstract reverence, but because it *works*. That really is the final say on the matter: as long as it is serving our purposes it will remain.

Comment: Thank you for your attention! I don't mean to push calculus out of the way. I asked third question because of first and second questions.

Comment: Frankly doing without calculus doesn't make the initial value issue go away. You still need to know the state of things at the beginning to understand the evolution, or you can work the evolution backward form the end state to get the initial state (subject to reversibility, of course).

Comment: We cannot work the evolution backward form the end state to get the initial state, because we don't know **real** value of the end state.

Comment: And? You don't know the real value of the initial state when working forward either. Every measurement is imprecise, and that puts limits on the precision with which any model will function.

Comment: I am not talking about measurements. I am talking about definitions. I think all of definitions in physics are vague, because all of them are related to vague states that we think we don't need to them.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say. That last sentence reads like you left some words out.

Comment: My English is terrible and probably I cannot say my mean well. And perhaps I cannot get your mean. BTW, I always respect you very much and I think this sentence isn't suitable for a physicist like you even if you face with a stupid person.  ***"That last sentence reads like you left some words out."*** I didn't expect you insult me at all.

Comment: You have left out a verb  "we don't need to ...  them" ; "define them?" , "describe them" ...  BTW this is not an insult, particulary as on the net with touch pads whole sentences may inadvertently disappear.

Comment: @lucas I apologize if you feel insulted. It was an invitation to re-phrase the comment. Otherwise there is nothing I can say because I don't understand.

Comment: @lucas You need to clarify what you're talking about. I have no idea what you mean by "real values" or "vague states", and "that we think we don't need to them" is almost on par with "has anyone really been far even as decided...". I think you are the one who's being vague, because you won't say exactly _what_ you think is vague.

Comment: @knzhou I don't think so. I need nothing. You need to clarify yourself if you cannot understand my **OBVIOUS** **GREAT** question.

Comment: @dmckee The problem in physics today is that instead of having a mathematical confirmation for physical phenomenons, we have a 'science' based on nothing that invents math just to support a theory that is based on nothing and has no practical value or possibility of usage.

Comment: @knzhou May you please come to the h-bar chatroom?

Comment: @knzhou I just wanted to apologize. That time I was so uncomfortable (and a little angry). I am sorry because of that!

Answer (score 5):

> 1. How are we sure that we don't need real values (for example initial values at zero time)?

In all experiments I have been involved in, we have initial values at zero time, with the +/- experimental errors.

> 2. Can we determine initial values at zero time (for example u(0) )?

ditto

> 3. Is it possible to have a physics by other mathematics except calculus so that we don't face with such this problems (initial values problem)?
>
> Can we have a physics by using other mathematics except calculus?

Maybe you should read up on the [history of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus#History)

> Modern calculus was developed in 17th-century Europe by Isaac Newton and Gottfried Wilhelm Leibniz, but elements of it have appeared in ancient India, Greece, China, medieval Europe, and the Middle East.

Physics as we know it started with Newton and Leibniz, and yes , it was calculus that made all the difference. Before them, mathematics and physics was one discipline and very close to philosophy.

So to consistently use "other mathematics" would bring us back to the times where algebra and geometry were ruling the observational models. They did not go very far.

In a sense we use "other mathematics " in [analogue computers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_computer)  All of our current computations are using calculus at some level, and as far as I know all of the attempts at new theories too.

Comment: Thank you very much! But 1. I have accepted an answer before and I can just upvote your answer. 2. May you please explain how do you measure initial values by experiment? (I mean at absolute zero time or beginning of the world)

Comment: It will depend on the model . For the Big Bang model one measures now to the accuracy possible , +/- error, and extrapolates to the 0+/- error, which of course is huge, using calculus of course.  Laboratory experiments are within a time interval, and zero time starts with the clock +/- error of clock.

Answer (score 3):

Physical laws are usually described in terms of [hyperbolic differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_partial_differential_equation). In such equations, the Cauchy problem is well-posed, i. e., if you know the value of your variable and some of its derivatives at the initial time, you can integrate them *locally* in order to find them at other times. That is the case of classical mechanics and quantum mechanics. In general relativity, the situation depends on the casual structure of spacetime, and people usually look for [globally hyperbolic manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_hyperbolic_manifold).

In the paragraph above, the most important word is *locally*. If you want to predict the outcome of some experiment, you only need to plug in your differential equations the initial setting of your lab (by initial I mean at the start of your experiment, not at the start of the Universe). You don't have to know the initial state of Andromeda or Japan.

Why do we need hyperbolic equations, and therefore, calculus? Because it is the **only** way to write laws of physics that *make predictions about the future*. Imagine for one moment that initial values are not necessary: so I read a question about the rôle of calculus in physics and, since my actions are not determined by initial values, I decide to write about agriculture in Cambodia instead of hyperbolicity. Do you think that our world works like that? No, things happen cuased/affected by previous events, by initial values. And we need calculus to model this experimental fact.